Rider .NET IIS 2024.2
I'm looking into running my project file locally in IIS, which years before I was running simply as is in Visual Studio. Now in Rider, not long ago they have introduced the feature to be able to run Web Apps via IIS, instead of just Express only.
However, whenever I'm running the project via IIS, It automatically places <UseIIS> setting in the csproj file. I'd like to achieve this without applying this setting in my project file. Is there a way to do this? The "Store as project file" section does not seem to work, or has no effect, or runs into a weird "folder must be in project folder" error.


Jetbrain welcomes your feature requests via https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

I'd like to achieve this without applying this setting in my project file. Please spceify what is this? And check the IIS log or find the Rider log in HELP menu for more information about the failure of Store as project file.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-28561/SaveServerSettingsInUserFile-csproj-seems-to-be-ignored
